# Possible to combine two lines of code into one

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Searching through a database looking for matches.  Need to log the matches as well as though that don't match so I have the full database but those that match I specifically need to know the part that matches.

```
serv = ['6:00am-9:00pm', 'Unavailable', '7:00am-10:00pm', '8:00am-9:00pm', 'Closed']
if self.serv[datas] == 'Today':
    clotime.append('')
elif self.serv[data] == 'Tomorrow':
    clotime.append('')
elif self.serv[data] == 'Yesterday':
    clotime.append('')
else:
    clo = re.findall('-(.*?):', self.serv[data])
    clotime.append(clo[0])
```

The bulk majority of the data ends up running through re.findall but some is still left for the initial if/elif checks.

Is there a way to condense this code down and do it all with re.findall, maybe even with just one line of code.  I need the everything(entire database) gone through/logged so I can process through the database correctly when I go to display the data on a map.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and provide some sample input and correct output? [MCVE]. Is the first key really different to the rest or just a typo?

Comment: Try http://ideone.com/vkJqra

Answer (score 0):

Using anchors you can match a whole string

```
clo = re.search('^(?:To(?:day|morrow)|Yesterday)$|-(.*?):', self.serv[data])
if clo is not None:
    clotime.append(clo.group(1))
```

With your example list:

```
serv = ['6:00am-9:00pm', 'Unavailable', '7:00am-10:00pm', '8:00am-9:00pm', 'Closed']

clotime = []
for data in serv:
    clo = re.search('^(?:To(?:day|morrow)|Yesterday)$|-(.*?):', data)
    if clo is not None:
        clotime.append(clo.group(1))

print(clotime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
clo = re.findall('-(\d+):', self.serv[data])
clotime.append(clo[0] if clo else '')
```

If I understood your existing code it looks like you want to append an empty string in the cases where a closing hour couldn't be found in the string? This example extracts the closing hour but uses an empty string whenever the regex doesn't match anything.

Also if you're only matching digits it's better to be explicit about that.